# How can I fill in sequential numbering with a number that has a dash

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have to populate an excel file with the following format:

10001-1,
10001-2,
10002-1,
10002-2,
10003-1,
10003-2

The numbers will go up to 15000-1 & 15000-2

Is there any formula to do this?

Comment: `=10000+ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0) & "-" & 1-(ROW()-EVEN(ROW()))`

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the first cell and copy/drag down:

```
=INT((ROW(A1)-1)/2)+10001&"-"&MOD(ROW(A1)-1,2)+1
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

or if you have Office 365 and want just one formula to spill the results:

```
=INT(SEQUENCE(10000,,10001,0.5))&"-"&MOD(SEQUENCE(10000,,0),2)+1
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Scott!!!

Comment: @PaulA If either of the answers are the one you used, please consider marking it as the correct one.  It will mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this a manual way because that's what I know.

Use column A for your 10001, 10001 (again), 10002, 10002 (again)
Use column B, and in `B1` type `1`, and in `B2` type `2`. Copy and paste this down to the end of the last value in column A.

Now, in column C, `=concat(A1,"-",B1)` and then copy that down to the last row in column A (or B)

[image]

I'm sure there are smarter ways to do it, though.